# Can't connect to mysql 5.6 database

Tags: c#, mysql, localhost, database-connection

I have been trying to connect to a MySQL database but have been getting exception 0x80131904: The server was not found. I know the server is running and I can query it through the command line. I have also made sure skip networking is not enabled. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to database...");

        SqlConnection sqlserver = new SqlConnection("user id=<removed>;" +
                                  "password=<removed>;server=localhost;" +
                                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                  "database=ircbot; " +
                                  "connection timeout=5");

        try
            {
            sqlserver.Open();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            Console.ResetColor();
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ResetColor();
            }

        Console.ReadLine();
        }    //end main


    }  //end class Program
```

Comment: are you trying to connect to sql server or mysql?

Comment: I am trying to connect to mysql

Comment: `SqlConnection` is *only* for connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server. You can't use it to connect to MySQL.

Comment: To connect to MySQL from C# see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-tutorials.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SqlConnection` is *only* for connecting to Microsoft SQL Server, you can't use it to connect to any other DBMS like MySQL.

To be able to connect to MySQL from C# you need the [MySQL Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/connector-net-x-devapi-reference.htm). It comes with a `MySqlConnection` class and corresponding data reader and parameter classes.

An introduction can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/connector-net-x-devapi-getting-started.htm#!).

Answer (score 0):

Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of 'localhost' as your server.

Comment: Why do you think this makes a difference?

Comment: When I write my php script to connect to my database, it does not work when I use localhost but it does when I enter 127.0.0.1.  Don't know why, but that's what happens.

Comment: @MichaelDeluca: Thanks for the clarification. Just wanted to make sure your answer is actually based on something :)

Answer (score 0):

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
string myConnectionString;

myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
"pwd=12345;database=test;";

try
{
conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
conn.Open();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```